# $state.go doesn't seems to be working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where when click on searched item i need to load different state

Here is my html code

```
<span class="item-title" ng-click="fnViewProfile()">
      <span> {{item.name}} </span>
</span>
```

below is my controller code:

```
$scope.fnViewProfile = function() {
        $state.go("ViewProfile", {
            "id": 10215
        });
    }
```

In my app.js i have a resolve function where i did ajax call to get the data before the html gets loaded

```
.state('ViewProfile', {
            parent: 'home',
            url: '/ViewProfile:id',
            templateUrl: 'views/ViewProfileView.html',
            controller: 'ProfileViewCtrl',
            resolve: {
                profile: function(DashboardService, $stateParams, $scope) {
                    debugger;
                    var userId = $stateParams.id;
                    var userData;
DashboardService.fnGetUser(userId).then(function(oResponse) {
                        userData = oResponse.data;

                    })
return userData;
                }
            }
```

In controller of ViewProfile state i am passing the profile service

```
angular.module('talentGraphApp')
.controller('ProfileViewCtrl', function($scope, $state, DashboardService, profile) {
    debugger;
    $scope.profile = profile;
    console.log(profile);
});
```

But i am unable to get profile in the console.

I dont understand where i am going wrong

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to `return` inside the promise. `return oResponse.data;`

Comment: Why you inject `$scope` in `resolve`?

Comment: I forgot to remove $scope there but still in ViewProfile state i couldn't get profile service

Comment: I think you forgot to add / in templateUrl after viewProfile. it should be url: '/ViewProfile/:id',

Comment: you know js is asynchronous. So the `return` stmt is executed first before you get response from `DashboardService.fnGetUser` service

Comment: @AvinashRaj,
Yes but resolve seems to be executed first before going to the next state controller but i am unable to get profile service there

Comment: @AvinashRaj , so could you let me know the solution please

Comment: @Shikhathakur already an answer there..

Answer (score 1):

In the `resolve` you return `userData` before it has been assigned inside the promise callback, so it is undefined when you pass it to controller

Return the promise instead

Change to

```
 resolve: {
      profile: function(DashboardService, $stateParams) {                      
             var userId = $stateParams.id;            
             return DashboardService.fnGetUser(userId).then(function(oResponse) {
                        // return as resolved value
                        return oResponse.data;    
             });    
        }
}
```

Also there is no `$scope` in the routing config